Errors happen when open Rstudio, continue to pop up blank windows. How can I handle this?
When I try to open Rstudio (a new working environment from desktop,a .R file or a R project), it starts to pop up several blank windows and ends up as shown in figure 1. When I press "reload", it might successfully open one of my previous projects (randomly), or it just cannot stop generating new windows. And at the same time, it continues to pop up new blank windows until a project is opened.

I googled this problem and guessed this might because the computer wants to continue the previous session and load the cache.So I deleted sessions from Rstudio folder. But after this it still doesn't work. After that, I update Rstudio, reinstall Rstudio, and reinstall R. All above failed.
And I found that there are no problem with R.The log of R studio is shown like this:
2024-10-10T17:49:28.412Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-10-10T17:58:58.880Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-10-10T18:03:18.650Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-10-13T19:35:59.348Z ERROR Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:43035: Error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (-102) loading 'http://127.0.0.1:43035/'
2024-10-20T12:03:26.259Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-25T20:58:19.458Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-25T21:04:18.742Z ERROR IpcError: getStartupErrorInfo: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
2024-11-25T21:04:46.910Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-25T21:05:28.145Z ERROR Failed to load file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\error_window\index.html: Error: ERR_ABORTED (-3) loading 'http://127.0.0.1:9889/'
2024-11-25T21:07:00.461Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-25T21:07:54.717Z ERROR Failed to load file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\error_window\index.html: Error: ERR_ABORTED (-3) loading 'http://127.0.0.1:28669/'
2024-11-25T21:19:32.489Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-25T21:52:56.102Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-25T21:52:56.110Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-25T21:52:56.111Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-25T21:52:56.111Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-25T21:53:56.749Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-25T21:56:58.565Z ERROR IpcError: getStartupErrorInfo: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
2024-11-25T22:00:40.227Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-25T22:02:28.702Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-25T22:03:08.490Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-25T22:12:27.276Z ERROR IpcError: getStartupErrorInfo: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
2024-11-26T00:53:20.737Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T01:25:58.539Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-26T01:25:58.541Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-26T01:25:58.541Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-26T01:25:58.542Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-26T01:25:58.542Z ERROR Main window closed unexpectedly
2024-11-26T09:23:22.680Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T09:25:31.180Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T10:01:23.746Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T10:02:07.983Z ERROR IpcError: getStartupErrorInfo: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
2024-11-26T10:10:17.901Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T10:11:01.421Z ERROR Failed to load file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\error_window\index.html: Error: ERR_ABORTED (-3) loading 'http://127.0.0.1:26051/'
2024-11-26T10:11:01.741Z ERROR IpcError: getStartupErrorInfo: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
2024-11-26T10:12:20.525Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T12:49:45.197Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T13:43:35.815Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T13:47:53.740Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T13:53:38.823Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T14:16:13.653Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T14:17:05.268Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'
2024-11-26T14:22:49.406Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file://C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\.webpack\renderer\splash\index.html'

